# Over 59k of Android push subscribers were opted out overnight

Tags: sfdcmobilesdk-android, react-native-marketingcloudsdk

I hope you can help if not with a solution, at least with some direction.

Last night, over 59k of our previously opted in Android mobile subscribers were opted out in mass in Marketing Cloud with a "servicefeedback" optout reason.

We have a standard react native sdk plugin integration and so far, we've had no major issues with the Android implementation.

Upon contacting the support, they gave their regular general answer by sending me what optout statuses mean. They are saying the error they see on their side is NotRegistered. But it's extremely hard to believe that such a huge number of our android subscribers either deleted or opted out in mass. Also, the optout timestamps are so close to each other, within seconds or minutes.

We're kind of lost for suggestions, so anything you might advise on would be quite helpful.